# When does PostgreSQL create a temporary table under the hood?

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

What are the cases that make PostgreSQL create temporary tables without being explicitly told except for join operations ?

Answer (score 1):

Never. A temporary table is a specific thing, and that specific thing is never created implicitly as far as I know.  There are things which "can be thought of as" temporary tables, but they are not the same thing as temporary tables.  They are analogies, not identities.

Many things can be backed by temporary files, but that also is not the same thing as a temporary table.